# Symfony: escape single quote string from database?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I need to generate a link with a Javascript confirmation dialog using Symfony's `link_to()` method. The confirmation dialog text gets some of it's content from a database entry:

```
<?php echo link_to( "click here", 'category/delete?id='.$id, array( 'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete the category: '.$category->getName().'?' ) ) ?>
```

But if the database entry has a `single quote` in it, the confirm dialog doesn't work because the generated JS is surrounded with single quotes. So if I have a category called "John's Articles", the generated JS starts like this:

```
<a onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the category: John's Articles?')) { var f = document.createElement('form'); f.styl.... etc... "
```

So, the single quote in there screws up the confirmation, etc...

Anyways I thought I would simply run `$category->getName()` through `addslashes()` but it didn't add any slashes... I also tried saving out the category name as a separate variable ahead of time and adding slashes to that. But it didn't add any. Then I started looking at Symfony's [escaping methods](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/EscapingHelper) and found methods like `esc_entities()` but they resulted in the text looking like `John&amp;#039;s Articles`.

What do I do? All I want to do is add in a single slash before single quotes in that string. I never tried `str_replace("'","\'",$category->getName())` but THAT didn't even do anything. I can create my own basic string in my template like `Alex's Test` and `addslashes()` to it just fine. It's just this value from the database that I can't add any slashes to.

When I look at the value in the database, it looks just like `John's Articles`. There are no special characters or encoded characters.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

I've tried the following code with the following results:

```
echo $category->getName()."<br/>";

echo addslashes($category->getName())."<br/>";

$tmp = $category->getName();
echo addslashes($tmp)."<br/>";

$tmp = addslashes($category->getName());
echo $tmp."<br/>";

$tmp = "Testing's the Testing";
echo addslashes($tmp)."<br/>";

$tmp = str_replace("'","\\'",$category->getName());
echo $tmp;
```

Results:

```
John's Articles
John's Articles
John's Articles
John's Articles
Testing\'s the Testing
John's Articles
```

The values from the database simply will not get slashes added to them...

Comment: as I know in php doing single quote prevent php from substituting variables, so you show us not exact the code you are working with, because 'Are you sure you want to delete the category: $category->getName().' won't be replaced withh $category->getName() value, am I wright?

Comment: I missed the quote in the code above. Look again.

Comment: ok, so have you tried to do str_replace("'","\\'",$category->getName())?

Comment: See above again, tried that along with many other things.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just use

```
addslashes($category->getName())
```

But you need assign returned value to other variable, ex.

```
$nameWithSlashes=addslashes($category->getName())
```

Answer (score 0):

use json_encode() when inserting into Javascript. It's specifically intended to turn arbitrary data structures into syntactically valid Javascript.

```
<?php echo link_to( ....snip snip...  category: '. json_encode($category->getName()) .'?' ) ) ?>
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^                    ^
```

will take care of the problem, without any "risky" regexes/string replacements.

Comment: All that seems to do is put double quotes around the category name: `"John's Articles"`.